# How to add a mass point in a confidence interval plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using the `dwplot` function from the `dotwhisker` package to plot the estimated coefficients. The code is below.

```
oz.dy.1 <- dwplot(td.oz.1, vline = geom_vline(xintercept = 0.0, colour = 'grey60', linetype = 'dashed'),
                  dot_args = list(aes(shape = model), size = 3)) %>%
  relabel_predictors(c('6'='6','5'='5','4'='4','3'='3','2'='2','1'='1',
                       '-2'='-2','-3'='-3','-4'='-4','-5'='-5')) + 
  xlab('Estimated Cofficients') + ylab('Leads and lags') + 
  ggtitle('Panel A') + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        legend.position = c(0.2,0.2)) + 
  coord_flip()
```

After the drawing, I'd like to add a mass point of `(-1,0)` into the plot, as shown in the figure below. It is the point I omitted from the regression.
[image]

The data can be found below. Thanks for your help!

```
 dput(td.oz.1)
structure(list(term = c(-2, -3, -4, -5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), estimate = c(-1.15114935051818, 
-0.963118572186544, -0.364425902685037, -1.35500696989404, -1.17043511366917, 
-1.77833168909803, -3.3970581302449, -4.31347867631756, -6.73256361939005, 
-8.18143865997518), std.error = c(0.599542571519325, 0.672486715698684, 
0.761384311125982, 0.919514932469594, 0.605107549716387, 0.7248074830269, 
0.798354719549293, 0.921425457867459, 1.07697341350806, 1.43780642313582
), statistic = c(-1.92004605711486, -1.43217486636284, -0.478635949493235, 
-1.47361062017211, -1.93425964395544, -2.45352280535442, -4.25507364967128, 
-4.68131050589881, -6.25137402181533, -5.69022263938123), p.value = c(0.0548562501535601, 
0.152098367975352, 0.632199174097253, 0.140591077778375, 0.0530853456430899, 
0.014148941461198, 2.0925882144009e-05, 2.85594323369196e-06, 
4.09257531963403e-10, 1.27392299877883e-08), model = c("Without state trend", 
"Without state trend", "Without state trend", "Without state trend", 
"Without state trend", "Without state trend", "Without state trend", 
"Without state trend", "Without state trend", "Without state trend"
)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I tried the `annotate` and modified my plot code as below. Notice that `y` is character. The problem is the `annotate` messed up the order. See the new plot below.

```
oz.dy <- dwplot(model.oz, vline = geom_vline(xintercept = 0.0, colour = 'grey60', linetype = 'dashed'),
                  dot_args = list(aes(shape = model), size = 3)) %>%
  relabel_predictors(c('6'='6','5'='5','4'='4','3'='3','2'='2','1'='1',
                       '-2'='-2','-3'='-3','-4'='-4','-5'='-5')) + 
  xlab('Estimated Cofficients') + ylab('Leads and lags') + 
  ggtitle('Panel B: Ozone concentration') + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        legend.position = c(0.2,0.2)) + 
  coord_flip() + 
  annotate(geom="point", colour="red", x=0, y='-1', shape=16, size=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can make the trick using `ggplot2` and adding the number you wish:

```
binned <- bind_rows(td.oz.1,data.frame(term=-1,model="Without state trend"))
oz.dy.1 <- dwplot(binned, vline = geom_vline(xintercept = 0.0, colour = 'grey60', linetype = 'dashed'),
                  dot_args = list(aes(shape = model), size = 3)) %>%
  relabel_predictors(c('6'='6','5'='5','4'='4','3'='3','2'='2','1'='1','-1'='-1',
                       '-2'='-2','-3'='-3','-4'='-4','-5'='-5')) +
  xlab('Estimated Cofficients') + ylab('Leads and lags') + 
  ggtitle('Panel A') + 
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, hjust = 0.5),
        axis.title.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.title.y = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size = 13),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 13),
        legend.position = c(0.2,0.2)) + 
  coord_flip() +
  geom_point(aes(x = 0,y=5),color='red',size=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Well. This is very nice. However, how can I add the `-1` tick on the horizontal line?

Comment: Yes. The position is correct. We just need to create the `-1` tick on `x`. I also tried `annotate` and the trick appeared however the order was messed up. See my edit.

Comment: @YabinDa I have updated the solution. Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi Duck, I have one more question. I am trying to add a vertical line to the final plot at the tick of `-1`. Since the coordinate is flipped, I use the code `geom_hline(yintercept = -1,colour = 'red', linetype = 'dashed')` However, the line just won't appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Problem solved. I need to change the position from `-1` to `5`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

how about

```
+ annotate(geom="point", colour="red", 
    x=-1, y=0, shape=16, size=3)
```

or something like that?  (It's possible that you'll have to switch `x` and `y` since you have used `coord_flip()` ...)

Because your axis is actually discrete (the numbers represent *categories*), and x/y are flipped, you need to set `y=5.5` (between the -2 and 0 categories):

```
+ annotate(geom="point",colour="red",pch=1,
   y=5.5,x=0,size=5)
```

For the axis tick you could use

```
 + annotate("segment", y=5.5, yend=5.5, 
    x=-Inf, xend=-11)
```

but I'd probably recommend a geom_vline (or geom_hline, can't tell because of coord_flip)

Comment: Thanks. It's an option. I tried your code and still got a problem. I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The problem is partially solved. The remaining question is how to create the `-1` trick on the `x` axis (after the filp).

Comment: The problem with `geom_hline` and `geom_vline` is the `-1` tick needs to exist. Otherwise, the line cannot be plotted.

Comment: ?? I'm suggesting drawing the line at a coordinate of y=5.5, which corresponds to the position of -1 on the scale you've got.

Comment: the alternative would be to run `broom::tidy()` and set up the plot yourself, using `geom_pointrange()` and with a continuous x scale rather than a discrete x scale